# Adjust formula automatically when a row reference changes

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

I have two workbooks.  [Student Attendance](https://i.stack.imgur.com/szGJj.png) The first contains a column of names of school students.  The rest of the columns include attendance - "time in", "time out" and "total hours" for each day the school is open during the month.

The second workbook [Client Tab](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ueGew.png) contains a tab for each student.  Columns are "date", "time in", "time out" and "total hours."  It then adds all daily hours and multiplies by hourly rate to arrive at total due for billing purposes.  These items are linked from the fist workbook.  It works great as long as I don't add/remove names and resort names A to Z.  When I do this, some names will appear in a new row number and the second workbook formulas are looking for the old row number information.  Here is an example:

```
=IF('...\[Attendance.xlsm]Current Month'!AO$30="","",'...\[Attendance.xlsm]Current Month'!AO$30)
```

In the above formula, when the student roster is changed, this client may now be on row `AO$31` instead of `AO$30`.

How can I adjust formula to make this change automatically? Right now, I change it manually with the "Find and Replace" option - Find `$30` and replace with `$31`.

Comment: The use of an `IF()` function in this context appears to be relatively unsafe, particularly considering that you have changing names etc. Why not simply use a `VLOOKUP()` or similar. Could you please provide an example of your data, otherwise it is difficult to help.

Comment: _Maybe_ not using an absolute reference for your rows will do the trick? See [here](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/switch-between-relative-absolute-and-mixed-references-dfec08cd-ae65-4f56-839e-5f0d8d0baca9) for info on absolute vs relative references

Comment: The absolute reference suggestion unfortunately didn't work.  Thanks anyway.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Dealing with the problem stated is simple:  use a lookup based upon each Client Spreadsheet's cell B14 being the lookup value and the lookup range being the Attendance Spreadsheet's column D, starting in cell D7. The return would be a cell (well, lots of them to choose from, but they come in sets for the dates it would seem, and each set is distinct) in the row found. `INDEX` is probably the natural for this as you can easily control the three column set returned while `XLOOKUP` and `VLOOKUP`, for example, would be a little tougher for that. This lookup is simple and very straightforward, very basic.

In this case, the looking up part returns the row, and so no referencing, absolute or not, is needed to specify the cell set to use for each date such is sought for in the Client workbook. Don't be fixated on just making a minor repair when there actually isn't one for this issue. Revamp things (in an easy way) and if you can't face the intricacies of then finding and using the right date set, then use your absolute addressing scheme on the columns, paired with the lookup's row.

That's the more interesting problem:  how to find the set of cells for each date. Not hugely interesting, but slightly less "usual" if you will.

**You should ask a question about how to do that, and provide enough information to reliably lay out a solution for you.** I would have, but there's all that space between what we see and one column we see mentioned ("AO") for the work to be wasted on if I guess wrongly.

Answer (score 0):

I found a simple answer - by blind luck.  All I had to do was name each row with the student's name in the Attendance workbook.  As names are added/deleted in this file the row references in formulas in the Client Tab workbook automatically update to reflect the new row number.

Although this solution did work, it had limitations - could not sort by student name without row reference error in formulas.  I couldn't wrap my head around to use INDEX as suggested so I used VLOOKUP with student name as the value.  It was a tedious process having to deal with 46 columns.  It's done and works perfectly.